# Как расположить все элементы внутри </div> в одну строку в HTML?

Tags: html, button

Я новичок. разрабатываю сайт-портфолио. Имеются 2 кнопки, как расположить их в ряд? Вот отрывок из кода:

```
<div>
<p><input type="button" value="Мои достижения"></p>
<p><input type="button" value="Связаться со мной"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Убрать теги **`<p>`**, потому что это "параграф" и он делает перенос строки

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Мои достижения">
    <input type="button" value="Связаться со мной">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Уже сказали, что здесь не нужен `<p>` — фактически это лишняя обертка, которая в данном случае еще и принудительно заставляет начинаться элементы с новой строки (потому что p — блочный элемент, а input — нет).

Вообще рекомендую изучить flexbox. Он как раз нужен для расстановки и упорядочивания  нескольких элементов, то есть нужен всегда и везде. Тут это будет так:

```css
div {
  /* Назначаем div флекс-контейнером, 
  по умолчанию элементы располагаются в строку */
  display: flex;
  /* Задаем выравнивание элементов: с одинаковым расстоянием между ними */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

input {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Мои достижения">
  <input type="button" value="Связаться со мной">
  <input type="button" value="Связаться со мной">
  <input type="button" value="Связаться со мной">
  <input type="button" value="Связаться со мной">
</div>
```